# sql insert into issues

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

This is kind of difficult to explain but will try to explain as much as possible.

I have a `table1` which has a column b and  key as column a.

I am trying to do a insert into table1 based on a select statement.

e.g.:

```
insert into table1(a,b) 
 select xyz.adata , getbdata(xyz.c) from xyztable xyz where xyz.adata = 234
```

my functions are big, so to keep it simple

suppose getbdata(int c) function does
something like (xyz.c - othertable.d - table1.b) for a given key,

When I do just the select, the getbdata(xyz.c) value is returned correctly.

But when I do an insert based on the select, the column b data is not getting
inserted correctly .

eg) if xyz.c is 50 , and othertable.d = 10 and table1.b = 0

```
select xyz.adata , getbdata(xyz.c) 
from xyztable xyz 
where xyz.adata = 234
```

would return something like

```
adatavalue , 40
```

but when I do a insert based on the above select into table1,

it would return something like

```
adatavalue , 0
```

(I think it does something like 50-10-40)

Bottomline - I am having an issue trying to do an insert based on a select which in turn does some calculations on the same table to be inserted.

I can always get the data from the above select statement and put it in a cursor and then try to insert into table1 .

But why is my insert based on the select statement failing.

Comment: I removed the "values" keyword from the insert statement.

Comment: Can you post the code for `getbdata()` function?

Comment: I  gave the getbdata() method as an example. The real functions used in our organization has many other sub functions and it is proprietary.  I think I want to know from all you experts , if you have ever faced this kind of issue that I am talking about..

Comment: Never mind guys .. I think I found what was the issue. Some of the internal functions were returning zeros for any issues.